Is Philosophy decaying into an antiquated subject?
Is Philosophy decaying into an antiquated Subject in 21st Century whereas lots of questions could be answered within modern Science?
Yes or No? Explain Why for your answer.
I have longed for asking this question until I found this stack exchange. Lots of things about consciousness could be answered in Cognitive Psychology/ Neuroscience. Lots of things of rational thoughts could be answered now in decision-making Psychology. The question of the start of existence of mankind could be found answer in Evolutionary Biology/ Evolutionary Psychology.
And my final question is:  What is the point of Philosophy's Existence in present's time?

"What is the point of Philosophy's Existence in present's time?" To inquiry about the (many) problems that science cannot adress: what is good, what is beauty, what is the essence of human, etc.

"decaying"? maybe... "Antiquated subject"? also symphonic music, chess playing, maratrhin are "antiquated"; who cares?

'(Why) is this negative outlook on the concept of philosophy misguided?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/86865/why-is-this-negative-outlook-on-the-concept-of-philosophy-misguided/86866#86866 Philosophy is a toolbox for novel problems, medical ethics for instance generates these. Investigating use of words in cases of paradoxes & edge-cases. Above all philosophy is about clarifying the way we think, & understanding the term consciousness is a good example because even in science no one can yet agree what it is, yet we feel we know

Philosophy used to be an exclusive club for the intellectual elite. High intelligence, for the sake of high intelligence. Nowadays, in America and in other places, there are pseudo-elites.

I read your profile. You might enjoy https://thephilosophyforum.com/


The answer to your first question is debated. There is a broad
spectrum of yes - no answers with  the corresponding argumentation.
E.g., the comment of @gs to a previous question states

Philosophy is the stump of science! It's what's left on this side of
campus after all the branches of science left and planted themselves
on the other side of campus, so that makes it the stump.

This view nearly reduces philosophy to the history of philosophy. It emphasizes and agrees with your viewpoint, that one domain after the other left philosophy when it developed its own method of research to become science.
Some philosophers speak about philosophia perennis (= eternal
philosophy). They mean that philosophy strives for knowledge which
is general, has existencial importance, is timelessly valid and
beyond further discussion.  History shows that no example of such
knowledge has been found.

Popper’s philosophy of falsificationism therefore
dismisses the search for such knowledge. He proposes – at least for
a scientific approach – to consider general theories as hypotheses,
which can be put to test and confirmed or refuted.
IMO this turn is a great progress of philosophy of 20th century. Also the insight of Kant that
we construct experience with the means of our intuition and a set of
categories seems to me an insight that we cannot step behind in the future.

In any case, to form one’s own opinion about your first question requires
to read before a lot of philosophical primary sources. And to ask:
Which problem does the author discuss? What does he/she propose? How
does he argue? IMO it is not helpful to start with the buzzwords
from secondary sources like idealism, realism, hyperintentionalism,
transcendalism …

Concerning your second question: I doubt that many non-philosophers
would miss philosophy if it would vanish from our culture due to
some sudden event. At least, current philosophy has to show the
benefits of its study if its claims transcend everyday insights. These
benefits are not obvious.




Personal Note:
One of the things I've learnt in many decades of teaching is that when a student says: I am bored... or even I dont understand anything! it usually means You (the teacher) are effing up.
The difficulty is that the student typically does not recognize that he knows because of the Dunning-Kruger effect and the teacher does not hear because of an inverse Dunning Kruger effect.

So... Let's try and hear what you are really saying behind what you seem to be saying.
Reframing the question
Following the conversation below Dikran's answer, it appears that the real question lurking behind the seeming one is quite different from Philosophy being antiquated and decaying. Rather it appears that in the 21st century philosophy comes across as being narrow and therefore boring.
Traditional Philosophy introductions explicitly or implicitly go via A history (of western) philosophy approach.
Today in the age of google (and chatGPT) one can 'Fourier transform' time to space and go...
Cross Cultural
Below some typical examples hastily thrown together.
From across countries, cultures, religions, continents...
And please excuse the category-errors of juxtaposing Chinese and Asian, Christian and Japanese etc etc!
(Pan-)Asian
Buddha
Chinese
Lao Tzu, Chuang Tzu
Indian
Shankara, Ramana
Japanese
Dogen, D.T. Suzuki, Kitaro Nishida
Islamic
Mulla Nasreddin
Christian
Meister Eckhart
Native American
Vine Deloria, Black Elk, Moonhawk
Western (finally!)
One cannot put anything meaningfully here without either getting encyclopedic or partisan (or both!).
So I am just going to paraphrase a quote of Whitehead:

All of western philosophy is just footnotes to Plato


Apologize, this time your answer looks a bit like name dropping or showing us the favorites from your personal reading list. - Could you add some flesh to the names? Why just naming a specific philosopher on this list? Which of his works did you read, which philosophical insight did you find stimulating and valid, today and tomorrow? - Moreover, could you explain your remark concerning Fourier transformation? Thanks.

@JoWehler The Fourier transform transforms time to simultaneous frequencies (speaking very simplistically). So I am suggesting to switch from going by time order (of western) philosophy to space order of philosophies in different cultures and places. As for expanding: This is as I said in the direction of making a world philosophy encyclopedia!! In any case (1) I guessing the real question behind the seeming question. Its not yet been confirmed (2) The questioner may well be looking for something specific and definite eg. phil of math (3) Anyways its closed, so no point sweating over it

@JoWehler As for “Name-dropping” it's a bit of a stretch to claim that Buddha, Shankara, Lao Tzu are not widely known. So naming them is more a question of Yawn... Say something new... What is new is the suggestion that they need not be read as eastern exotica but can be read with a serious philosophical hat on. The only place where you could make that claim is the very obscure ones like the native American which is there not so much for the individuals listed as to say that serious philosophy can be found in unexpected locales. And in those cases there are links provided.

Philosophy is "the pursuit of knowledge".  That is never antiquated, or irrelevant.
IN the pursuit of knowledge, philosophers have developed some theories about useful ways to gain knowledge.  This sub-field is called epistemology.  One of those methods is empiricism.  There has been a lot of thought ABOUT how to do empiricism more rigorously, and that sub-field of philosophy is called the Philosophy of Science.
Science itself is an empirical method of investigation which was developed and is justified BY philosophy.
The different science fields are areas OF philosophy which philosophers investigated for long enough that the right terms, and frameworks of evaluation to understand it became settled, and that field was then able to spawn off as its own discipline.
Philosophy itself today continues to address those areas NOT yet well enough understood to be spawned off as their own disciplines.  This is not a well-structured set of issues, as it is the most difficult "leftovers" in the suite of all knowledge questions.
If you are looking for a tidy set of answers, philosophy therefore is a frustrating field.  It is often not clear what questions within a subject one should ask, how to define its terms, or how to investigate the subject.  There are proposed solutions presented by philosophers, and rebuttals and alternatives presented by their rivals, creating a muddled "mess" of contrary opinions.
That used to be the case for all current sciences too.  This process of speculation, criticism, counter proposal, etc. eventually converged for some aspects of philosophy, leading to our current sciences.  In the remainder, it hasn't yet.

@DikranMarsupial  Yes, the methods of science were developed by philosopher/scientists.  The articulator of our current scientific method, Karl Popper, noted that the "boundary problem" for science did NOT have a boundary between science and philosophy -- because science is just a subset of philosophy, and the two blend into each other.

Lots of confusion arises from the fact that the word "philosophy" has been used for a long time to encompass all research of knowledge, including what is now called philosophy in schools and academia and other sciences. For example, Isaac Newton's major book published in 1687, where he exposes his theories of motion and natural gravitation, was titled "The Mathematical Principles of Natural Philosophy"
At the time researchers were mostly what we now called "the renaissance man", it is to say an erudite who masters many if not all areas of knowledge, from philosophy proper to history, mathematics, physics, mecanics, biology and arts. As knowledge progressed and expanded, it became impossible to be versed in all branches of research, and people started specializing. That's were philosophy started to become a branch by itself, tackling problems branches of science focused on physical phenomenon couldn't handle, the aptly named "metaphysics" (above physics).
Around the end of the XVIII century the idea that it was impossible, or possible in ver narrow scope, to decide on metaphysical problems one way or another started to gain traction (see Critique of Pure Reason). As a result what was left to philosophy per se is the study of reasoning itself, the study of logic and the analysis, critique and production of concepts, it is to say the ideas we use as reasoning tools and designate by means of words.
It will often happen that people use the same word for completely different ideas, notably when discussing abstract ideas. A go to example being "family values": people will often bring it up and say they like "family values", but when we start breaking it down we soon realize they are talking about something completely different. Often the break down will result in a logical contradiction, revealing the locutors had actually no idea what they were talking about and just used some fill in word without grasping the underlying concept.
The view that philosophy is mostly the study of concepts and language has been supported by Wittgenstein in the Tractatus Logico Philosophicus, were he tries to analyse the notion of sense, what makes it so that a statement makes sense. He formulates the difference between philosophy and science, and what remains as the exclusive domain of philosophy, this way:

4.11 The totality of true propositions is the whole of natural science (or the whole corpus of the natural sciences).


4.111 Philosophy is not one of the natural sciences. (The word "philosophy" must mean something whose place is above or below the natural sciences, not beside them.)


4.112 Philosophy aims at the logical clarification of thoughts. Philosophy is not a body of doctrine but an activity. A philosophical work consists essentially of elucidations. Philosophy does not result in "philosophical propositions", but rather in the clarification of propositions. Without philosophy thoughts are, as it were, cloudy and indistinct: its task is to make them clear and to give them sharp boundaries.

In order to clarify a proposition, a philosopher will have to rely on facts gathered by other branches of science. In the case of family values, our example above, they might have to rely on facts gathered by historians or sociologists, etc.  But the work of analysis itself is philosophic in nature.

I think the importance of Philosophy (or philosophical thinking) is more important now than ever. Lest I sound like the fangirl that I am, let me justify this :)
True to Philosophy, even its definition is a subject of much philosophizing :) To me, Philosophy is the study of ultimate foundations. That is what makes it a unique pursuit. When I see "The Philosophy of X" I expect analysis of the core concepts and assumptions supporting X.
Here in the US we have a very polarized, skeptical, and suspicious electorate - I suspect we're not alone, just more "out in the open". It's easy to get wrapped up in your viewpoint and confirmation bias (or full blown conspiracy thinking). On top of that, we have several issues that have come to the top of the political debate (even if they are no the most pressing issues overall). Examples include abortion, transgender rights, Ukraine support, and immigration.
Taking a philosophical lens to vexing social problems can help, at a minimum, engender intellectual empathy where there was once hostility. At its best, it can help move the debate forward in a principled way, instead of each side resorting to winner-take-all/zero-sum ideological warfare.
A great example of this is this book (falls on the pro-choice side but it's not an ideological screed - it doesn't say ALL abortions are moral, which is interesting): https://www.abortionarguments.com/p/this-book-introduces-readers-to-many.html
I also like Graham Oppy's work on religion. His style of thought is very philosophical and precise, without a ton of rhetorical devices: https://archive.org/details/graham-oppy-the-best-argument-against-god
For the trans debate, I've enjoyed these:

Arguing against "many sexes": https://www.heritage.org/gender/commentary/why-states-must-define-sex-precisely
Sober take on "self gendering" by Kathleen Stock: https://www.philosophersmag.com/essays/253-material-girls-why-reality-matters-for-feminism-a-review
Philosophical review of impasses in trans right debate: https://www.julianbaggini.com/why-are-trans-rights-so-divisive/

Regardless of your stance on these issues, you'll see in all of these an even-tempered and methodical view of the issue. I came away from these works with a deeper appreciation of the issues and difficulties (and the key assumptions underlying them).
Of course, philosophy has also helped spark a great many ideological wars, so maybe it’s a wash. But for me, I've been reaching for SEP and the philosophical literature more often the past few years, as we grapple with a very divided nation and deeply held views on both sides (myself included).

I want to point one area which is central to philosophy and likely will remain central.
It is the study of self-reference in all possible contexts. Self-reference leads to multiple paradoxes in logic, mathematics, set theory, quantum mechanics, ethics, cosmology, programming, etc.
It includes Liar paradox, Russel paradox, Goedel incompleteness theorem, Halting problem, Anthropic pricnciple, Measurement problem, Grandfather paradox, closed timelike curves, and even ethical problems related to animal rights, abortions, medical ethics or artificial intelligence.
Particularly, self-reference poses a huge challenge to the long-established scientific method because scientific method generally was not intended for the cases where the observed object and the observer are the same thing. Particularly, quantum theory is not applicable to such setup.
As such, very roughly speaking, I would say, modern philosophy is by more than a half a study of paradoxes and issues arising from various situations with self-reference.

Absolutely not. Wittgenstein said in the 'Tractatus' that philosophy is either above or below science, they are not at the same level.
I don't want to be accused of spreading 'conspiracy misinformation', but most you modern science is a dead-end fraud. It does not answer any deep / fundamental questions, it is ideologically motivated, it is a business, and there is a ton of marketing and lies.
Let me give you a few examples. They awarded the noble prize to some japanese guy who claimed he can make regular cells turn into stem cells genetically. Turned out it's just a scam, and everybody forgot now. They used to claim that they clone animals. However, that was a lie, nothing was ever cloned. They talked about those stem cells that can regenerate any tissue in the body, yet not a single handicapped person has risen from the wheelchair despite thousands of claims from scientists, do those stem cells even exist? There is this nonsense about mapping / reconstructing the human brain, that is absolute fiction, they have not even been able to create a full working model of the nervous system of earthworms. Psychology is not science. Recent events involving some fashionable diseases confirm all of my claims, 'scientists' were pushing pure lies and nonsense upon us for 2 long years, and one of their mottos was 'trust science'. Global warming is also fake pseudo-science.
The very structure of modern science in western capitalist countries prevents it from achieving anything profound because of the grant system. They just give you a pile of cash to produce a result in 2 years. That timeframe is ridiculously short. Real intellectual breakthroughs sometimes take decades to achieve.
My amazing conclusion is that science is what is getting antiquated in the 21st century.

ekholm and those other characters just put forth some hypotheses that turned out all wrong. that is not a bad thing because they lived 100+ years ago and they were operating with obsolete newtonian mechanics. their concerns were mostly due to excessive amounts of coal burning in big european cities like london and berlin. do we still live in that steampunk era where coal burning is the main source of energy? also, global warming folks like you promoted wind / solar energy big time, it turned out to be a fail polluting the environment more and producing 1000 times less energy that nuclear

what rise in temperature has happened? i live in canada, and i clearly remember like 15 years ago summers were way longer and hotter, now winters are much colder and longer, why if the rise has happened? what drop in IR, how much is it? satellites have only been around for like 40 years, and this whole time global warming was already raging in full effect. also regarding political discussion tell me why the number one masterpiece of your 'science', al gore's 'inconvenient truth' turned out to be a fat falsification from beginning 'till end, and it was initially praised to heavens?
