# How can I debunk solipsism?

Tags: metaphysics, reality, solipsism

What if my consciousness is the only thing that is real? What if the entire world does not exist in a material way? What if only this moment exists? What if the past is an illusion? What if people etc. vanish when they are out my sight? What if my body as well as my surrounding vanishes when I sleep? PLEASE give me arguments against solipsism!

Comment: The answers to your questions won't change your experiences, so they are about (re)defining words rather than investigating your experiences. Getting stumped by the issues of solipsism is the philosophical equivalent of not being able fight your way out of a wet paper bag. [What are the best Arguments against solipsism?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/89321/what-are-the-best-arguments-against-solipsism/89322#89322)

Comment: So you don’t have Arguments against my hypothesis?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refuting Solipsism](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/53494/refuting-solipsism)

Comment: Non-dual experience is the only satisfactory answer to philosophical questions. All questions, really.