Is the principle of uniformity of nature an abduction or an analogy?
Is the principle of uniformity of nature an abduction or an analogy?
To what type of reasoning does the principle of uniformity of nature belong? Is it abduction, analogy, deduction?
Here they refer to the principle of the uniformity of nature.
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/15135/52276
What type of reasoning is used in this argument?

This is how I understood that using induction to justify belief in other minds is irrational. But in general, there is nothing irrational to use. Then how to draw conclusions?

The principle (so named by Mill) comes from Hume:"For all inferences from experience suppose, as their foundation, that the future will resemble the past... If there be any suspicion, that the course of nature may change, and that the past may be no rule for the future, all experience becomes useless, and can give rise to no inference or conclusion." So it is a kind of abduction akin to what Kant later called "transcendental argument", from experience to conditions of its possibility.

Point out the difference in how these arguments reach their conclusion: 1) My mind is responsible for my behavior. Other people look like me and have behaviors similar to mine. So other people also have minds. 2) My mind is responsible for my behavior. I know from my experience how people who have minds should behave. Other people behave the way people who have minds should behave because they actually have minds. Are these two different considerations or one and the same?


People have minds because they look like me. 2) People behave the way people who have minds should behave because they actually have minds. Are these the same considerations? or does one use induction and the other abduction?


I think the second argument is an elaboration of the first. The first only makes an analogy based on behavior, it is weaker. The second adds explanatory value. Based on my experience, I can point to driving forces that explain the behavior and sometimes can predict it. I can then argue that such complex behavior is hard to explain and predict without appealing to said driving forces. So if similar behavior is encountered elsewhere it is reasonable to posit analogous driving forces behind it, especially if it is predictive, and they presuppose a mind. This strengthens a mere behavioral analogy.

See Hume: " 'When the mind, therefore, passes from the idea or impression of one object to the idea or belief of another, it is not determined by reason, but by certain principles, which associate together the ideas of these objects, and unite them in the imagination. (T. 1.3.6.12)' Thus, it is the imagination which is taken to be responsible for underpinning the inductive inference, rather than reason. 1/2

In the Enquiry, Hume suggests that the step taken by the mind, 'which is not supported by any argument, or process of the understanding … must be induced by some other principle of equal weight and authority. (E. 5.1.2)' That principle is “custom” or “habit”. " 2/2

would it be reasonable to combine the argument by analogy with abduction? Other people have minds like mine because: 1) other people are similar to me biologically and have behavior similar to mine. (Principle of uniformity, induction, preservation of symmetry)


other people are similar to me and have behavior similar to mine, so the best explanation for other people's behavior will be that other people have minds, because it provides a simple and unified explanation for my behavior and the behavior of other people; it does not make me special among other people and does not give me a special status in the world;



it makes more sense because it has a simple and clear causal relationship: mental states and cognitive processes explain the behavior of other people much more simply and clearly (people share their thoughts and feelings because they really have thoughts and feelings. People act in a certain way because they they have mental states such as desire and motivation that make them act like that, etc.)



Solipsism does not make sense because the causal relationship is unclear (people share their feelings and thoughts and act as if they are governed by mental states such as desires and motivations, but in fact they do not have mental states) i.e. their behavior does not make sense. Are there circular reasoning or any errors or contradictions?


Neither. It is a principle.

Can I be more detailed please?

I have argued that the Uniformity Principle derives from the three Laws of Thought. The Academia.edu site is here:  https://www.academia.edu/41240897/Induction_and_the_Uniformity_Principle_derivation_of_the_principle_from_fundamental_axioms


Is the principle of uniformity of nature an abduction or an analogy?
To what type of reasoning does the principle of uniformity of nature belong? Is it abduction, analogy, deduction?

someone may hold the principle because:

it simply seems to match our observations so far (in which case it may be regarded as a product of 'empirical induction')
(they hold that) it's the 'simplest/best explanation' that accounts for the reliability of the scientific method itself (in which case it may be regarded as an 'abduction')
it is the same thing as principles of conservation of energy and momentum, per E. Noether's first theorem (a sort of 'deduction')

or even some other reason(s) that doesn't necessarily match any particular form of reasoning/inference, and there may be no final word on the matter

How does empirical induction differ from argument by analogy or ordinary induction?

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/15135/52276 Specifically, what type of reasoning is used here?

But isn't the principle of uniformity of nature used there, which is inductive? "It's this assumption of uniformity, similar outcomes from similar causes, that is the logical weak point in this argument."

@Arnold an assumption of uniformity (of some kind) is the foundation on which inductive inference starts.  I think of it this way:  I'm going to constuct a model.  I define a class of objects for which this model applies.  I derive some signular  model that describes the instances of that class.  Then, with respect to the features that define that model, the instances of that class are treated uniformly.  Now it might work out that I can't construct one such model, or I need to modify the defintion of the class to get the model to work, or (obviously) change the features of that model...

Still, at the end of the day, the goal is to have one model for all  members of a particular class.   So all members of that (final version of the) class are treated the same with respect to that model.

Is it reasonable to use the principle of uniformity (argument by analogy) to justify belief in the existence of other minds? Because it says here that using this argument will inevitably lead to solipsism. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#ArguAnal

To begin with, the terms abductive and inductive are so ill-defined that the  SEP has an entire article that tries (and in my view fails) to give an account of the difference between the two types of reasonings, and concludes that it is an unsettled question, so best of luck with that.
Loosely speaking, reasoning is abductive if it is making a judgement about the best explanation for a set of observations, which might or might not involve analogy. Perhaps a worked example might help. Let's consider the question of whether other people have minds. You can reason that they do in at least two ways, for instance:

You might observe that since you are a member of the same biological species as the rest of mankind, and since we all have the same basic ingredients (with a few exceptions), such as a head, two eyes, brain, heart, etc etc etc, and since we all function in more or less the same way, it would be odd if you were the only human to have a mind. That would be reasoning by analogy.

You might instead consider the hugely varied range of phenomena associated with human activity, such as language, industry, the arts, chess, the Large Hadron Collider, political debates, my immensely clever and funny novels, and so on and so on endlessly, and conclude that it would be impossible to imagine a better explanation for them than the assumption that people have minds. That would be reasoning by abduction.



But how can we draw conclusions about the existence of other minds if the principle of induction and analogy is subject to severe criticism and even as noted can lead to solipsism (although I don't understand how?) Abduction does not have a universally recognized set of criteria. The criteria are arbitrary and it is also not clear how to evaluate them. For example, the criterion of simplicity is divided into ontological simplicity in which solipsism wins and explanatory simplicity in which the existence of other minds wins.

There are no rules by which to determine what is simpler or what type of simplicity is preferred.

@Arnold expecting Philosophy to save the world is a vain hope :-)

See Wesley Salmon, The Uniformity of Nature (Philosophy and Phenomenological Research, 1953):

The attempt to establish the doctrine which as been known as the
"uniformity of nature" is a method which some of Hume's successors has
used to circumvent his "skeptical conclusions" regardinig induction. The suggestion of this method is to be found in Hume's work itself, ss when he says:


"... all inferences from experience suppose, as their foundation, that the future will resemble the past, and that similar powers will be conjoined with similar sensible qualities. If there be any suspicion that the course of nature may change, and that the past may be no rule for the future, all experience becomes useless, and can give rise to no inference or conclusion."


It is to be noted, of course, that although Hume regards belief in the uniformity of nature as a necessary condition of the possibility of inductive inference, he does not commit himself to saying that it is a sufficient condition.


There are three possible ways in which the doctrine of the uniformity
of nature might be incorporated into a philosophical systemt.


First, it might be regarded as an empirically established truth. John Stuart Mill is the outstanding historical proponent of this view. Second, it might be regarded as a truth which is established a priori. Kant, of course, maintains this position. Third, it might be held to be a postulate of knowledge, impossible to establish as true, but necessary to assume in order that inferences may be made. [...] Bertrand Russell in his book Human Knowledge (1923), gives
it its latest important expression.


"What is necessary is never unwise."

It is a mixture of induction and abduction (a word I had not known to have that meaning, but then I'm not alone).
Uniformity is the result of induction because we don't have contradicting evidence. The very foundation of science is that experiments are (in principle) reproducible, which implies that they yield the same result at different times and usually in different places. Additionally, our examination of the observable universe indicates that the laws of nature as we know them have been the same through most of the universe, spatially and temporally.
Uniformity is also the result of abduction because our observations are incomplete; the simplest assumption for the places and times we have not or cannot observe is that nature works just the same there as well. Of course, as is the case with all abduction, this is only a hypothesis.
One should point out the circular nature of the concept that nature is uniform: By definition, only reproducible traits are uniform! In practice, no experiment is exactly reproducible. The world is full of chaos and non-linear interactions. For example, every time we perform a billiard ball collision to demonstrate Newtonian mechanics the balls will bounce of slightly differently. But we "define the deviations away" and focus on the essence, the part that is reproducible, and declare that part as uniform.

plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#ArguAnal It says that using an argument by analogy to justify the existence of other minds inevitably leads to solipsism. What does it mean? How can an argument for the existence of other minds lead to solipsism?


Is the principle of uniformity of nature an abduction or an analogy?
To what type of reasoning does the principle of uniformity of nature belong? Is it abduction, analogy, deduction?

The principle itself is an observation about reasoning about the universe: we can reason about natural objects and phenomena that we cannot directly observe only by assuming that those objects and phenomena we have and do observe serve as adequate models.
I'm prepared to accept that, itself, as an axiom, but if you wanted an argument for it then that would be an exercise in logic -- deductive reasoning from premises that you choose to accept as more fundamental.
As for using the Principle, inductive reasoning (about nature) is the most direct application, but the principle underlies pretty much all natural reasoning. Without it, we have no way to ascribe any broader meaning to any of our observations, so as to reason abductively or deductively about them, either.  This is ultimately a question of what it means to "reason".

Here they refer to the principle of the uniformity of nature.
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/15135/52276
What type of reasoning is used in this argument?

It is best characterized as deductive reasoning from a particular application of uniformity of nature.  The argument is:

I observe in myself characteristics that I define collectively as "consciousness". [definition]

I observe a class of natural organisms, which includes me, that I call "human beings". [(loose) definition]

Human beings exhibit sufficient external and behavioral similarity to myself to justify assuming uniformity with respect to consciousness. [uniformity of nature, plus additional assumptions]

Since I am conscious, it follows that other humans must be too. [deduction from 1 & 2, based on 3]


Note well that I am just summarizing the argument made by the author of the referenced post, not asserting it myself.  Even its author acknowledges that appealing to uniformity is a weak point of that argument, which it is, but there isn't much else to it.  Overall, it rests on unsupported assumptions -- not uniformity itself, but that uniformity is applicable in this particular situation.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#ArguAnal It says that using an argument by analogy to justify the existence of other minds inevitably leads to solipsism. What does it mean? How can an argument for the existence of other minds lead to solipsism?

@Arnold, I take you to be referring to the last few sentences of that section, especially: "it is important to appreciate the difficulties thought to be associated with the idea that one learns from one’s own case what it is to think and feel: it is believed to lead inexorably to solipsism."  That's only peripherally about arguments in favor of other minds existing.  It's primarily about a specific idea that may be raised in the context of such an argument.  The implication is that it is problematic to try to use that particular idea in an argument against solipsism.

You can go into a little more detail, because as far as I know, the argument of analogy in favor of the existence of other minds can only be in one version and, accordingly, there can be no other contexts.

@Arnold, if you're interested in exploring that more deeply then please post it as a separate question in its own right.

Until babies learn this principle, the world appears to be "a buzzing, blooming confusion." Without it we would never be able to reason ourselves to sanity.
